# Docopt function argument issues

Tags: python

Im not entirely sure how to call my `tasklist` function with all the required arguments. Im guessing im getting the syntax wrong. Can anyone point out my stupidity please?

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Description:

Used for checking users logged into a list of servers.

Usage:
  hunter.py (-u <username>) (-p <password>) (-d <domain>) (-s <FILE>)
  hunter.py -h | --help
  hunter.py --version

Options:
  -u --username
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  -p --password
  -d --domain
  -s --serverfile=FILE
  """
from docopt import docopt
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError

def tasklist(serverlist, domain, username):
    for serverl in serverlist():
        try:
            print "%s Services Listed Below" % serverl
            cmd = 'tasklist /V /S %s -u%s\%s /FI "USERNAME eq $s"' % serverl, domain, username, domain
            print cmd
            subprocess.check_output(cmd)
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.returncode)

def getservers(servers):
        slist = open(servers).readlines()
        return [s.replace('\n', '') for s in slist]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
    print arguments
    serverlist = getservers(arguments['--serverfile'])
    print serverlist
    tasklist(serverlist,(arguments['<domain>'], ['<username>']))
```

**COMMANDLINE EXAMPLE**

`c:\Python27>hunter.py -u xpuser -p xpuser -d WORKGROUP -s servers.txt`

**TRACEBACK**

```
{'--domain': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--password': True,
 '--serverfile': 'servers.txt',
 '--username': True,
 '--version': False,
 '<domain>': 'WORKGROUP',
 '<password>': 'xpuser',
 '<username>': 'xpuser'}
['192.168.1.122', '192.168.1.121']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hunter.py", line 44, in <module>
    tasklist(serverlist,(arguments['<domain>'], ['<username>']))
TypeError: tasklist() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasklist()` function requires 3 arguments, you are passing just two. Replace:

```
tasklist(serverlist,(arguments['<domain>'], ['<username>']))
```

with:

```
tasklist(serverlist, arguments['<domain>'], arguments['<username>'])
```

Also, you don't need to call `serverlist`, it's a list, omit the parenthesis:

```
for serverl in serverlist:
```

Also, replace:

```
cmd = 'tasklist /V /S %s -u%s\%s /FI "USERNAME eq $s"' % serverl, domain, username, domain
```

with:

```
cmd = 'tasklist /V /S %s -u%s\%s /FI "USERNAME eq %s"' % (serverl, domain, username, domain)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks am now getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hunter.py", line 44, in <module>
    tasklist(serverlist, arguments['<domain>'], arguments['<username>'])
  File "C:\Python27\hunter.py", line 26, in tasklist
    for serverl in serverlist():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Thanks i knew it must be something simple. Yet another prob after fixing the `$s` in above code. im getting ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hunter.py", line 44, in <module>
    tasklist(serverlist, arguments['<domain>'], arguments['<username>'])
  File "C:\Python27\hunter.py", line 29, in tasklist
    cmd = 'tasklist /V /S %s -u %s\%s /FI "USERNAME eq %s"' % serverl, domain, u
sername, domain
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`